# Match values within 3 different tables in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 tables in PowerBI

```
Table 1
Num
111
222
333

Table 2
Number  Code
111      aa
333      cc
222      bb
444      ff
666      gg
```

These 2 tables are connected by the `Number` column

```
Which means the connected value looks like this-
    Number  Code
    111      aa
    222      bb
    333      cc
```

Now on my table 3 I have the following -

```
Table 3
Number  Code
111      aa
222      bc
222      bb
444      ff
666      gg
```

Now what I would like to do is to compare the code when the Number Matches. Means the Output should look like -

```
Number  Code  Result
111      aa    Y
222      bc    N
222      bb    N
444      ff    N
666      gg    N
```

Do anyone knows any solution to solve this challenge!

Comment: Why are the last 3 rows N? Are you trying to write a measure or a calculated column? If the latter, please make it explicit which table the calculated column belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Table 1 is relevant but it seems like you can just do a lookup and check if it matches.

```
Result =
IF (
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        Table2[Code],
        Table2[Number], Table3[Number]
    ) = Table3[Code],
    "Y",
    "N"
)
```

Comment: A single value for column 'Number' in 'Table3' cannot be determined?

Comment: So how do you want to handle that case? That shouldn't happen in the example you gave.

Comment: Shouldn't happen, but it does. Your answer doesn't work.

Comment: If you have multiple values, then it's not a basic lookup and you need to specify how to handle things. There are plenty of options (e.g. take the max, return a fixed value/blank, treat it as a list, etc.) but it all depends on what you are trying to do.